# How does Wired magazine achieve this thick underline link effect?

Tags: html, css

I noticed recently that Wired magazine has a blue underline for their links that is thick, crosses over text descenders, and a different colour from the text. Here's a [random page](http://www.wired.com/2014/07/art-science-and-an-insect-renaissance/) for an example.

I don't think this is done with a `bottom-border`, because it overlaps the text descenders. The colour different might be done with the new `-moz-text-decoration-color` and `text-decoration-color` declarations, but I can't determine if there's anything that helps one control the line thickness.

I have, of course, tried to go forensic by analyzing [their CSS](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/vendor/condenast/pangea/themes/wired/assets/css/wired-post.css?ver=1405035264), but it's minimized and complicated, and I can't machette my way through all the brush to get at the information I need. I tried searching for key terms like  `-moz-text-decoration-color` and `border-bottom`, but with no success.

Anyone know how they do it?

Comment: It's probably `box-shadow`

Comment: In future if you want to fine the CSS for any text on web, you can use Chrome Inspecter (F12) in your crome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inspect a link you'll see:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #CBEEFA;
box-shadow: 0px -4px 0px #CBEEFA inset;
```

You can read about the reasoning of using `box-shadow` in [this article](https://medium.com/designing-medium/crafting-link-underlines-on-medium-7c03a9274f9).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is the `border-bottom` there just for backward compatibility?

Comment: Probably yes. It is for that, but I can't say it's "just" for that

Comment: Any change anyone knows how to change the color of the box-shadow when the link is `:visited' and/or why they even used box-shadow at all. I can get the same effect with just a border.

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #cbeefa;  
box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #4CAECF
```

Which according to W3Schools

```
box-shadow: none|h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color |inset|initial|inherit;
```

> Note: The box-shadow property attaches one or more drop-shadows to the
>   box. The property is a comma-separated list of shadows, each specified
>   by 2-4 length values, an optional color, and an optional inset
>   keyword. Omitted lengths are 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inspect element tools of Chrome and Firefox. Right click on the link and click inspect element. It looks like this:

[image: inspect element]

You can see it is both border-bottom and box-shadow.

Answer (score 1):

They used to use a .png to get the effect, but I'm happy to see they've finally gone with the pure CSS method. This [quick guide explains how to do it via CSS stylesheet](https://ayrne.io/technology/how-to-create-wired-style-links-with-pure-css/) and also how to filter which elements the styling gets applied to.

For example, this would apply a Wired-style link underscore to all links on your website:

```
/*----Wired Style Links----*/
a:link{
   text decoration: none;
   box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #B4E7F8;
}
a:hover:link:{
background-color: #B4E7F8;
}
```

And this would exempt internal links (on yourwebsite.com) from being styled:

```
/*----Wired Style Links----*/
a[href*="//"]:not([href*="yourwebsite.com"]){
   text decoration: none;
   box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #B4E7F8;
}
a:hover[href*="//"]:not([href*="yourwebsite.com"]){
background-color: #B4E7F8;
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you could provide a CSS demonstration in your answer, while citing your link as a reference.